# Capitalized Component Not Rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, rendering

I am importing a component, but it does not render. The component is capitalized. I think there is something wrong with the import statement because when I remove it and replace  with "Navbar", it renders, but if i keep the import then it does not render.

```
import styles from "./style";
import { Billing, Business, CardDeal, Clients, CTA, Footer, Navbar, Stats, Testimonials, Hero } 
from "./components";

const App = () => { return (
  <div className="bg-primary w-full overflow-hidden">
    <div className={`${styles.paddingX} ${styles.flexCenter}`}>
      <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
       
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
);
  };

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>Navbar</div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Billing from "./Billing";
import CardDeal from "./CardDeal";
import Business from "./Business";
import Clients from "./Clients";
import CTA from "./CTA";
import Stats from "./Stats";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Testimonials from "./Testimonials";
import Hero from "./Hero";

export {
  Navbar,
  Billing,
  CardDeal,
  Business,
  Clients,
  CTA,
  Stats,
  Footer,
  Testimonials,
  Hero,
};
```

If i exchange the component

for basic text like "Navbar" or "Navbar" it does not render either. These 2 display when I remove the import components statement.
When i control click , it brings me to the correct Navbar component.

I am following a yt tutorial
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_hoobank

my repo is here: https://github.com/lukasmckaine22/userbet_landing_page

I made sure the component was capitalized. I confirmed the component actually leads to the correct component by control clicking it. I confirmed the code renders plain text only when the import is removed. I confirmed the import leads to the correct file by control clicking. I tried only importing the Navbar with and without brackets. I changed the import directory to pull the navbar directory.

Comment: can you share the code sandbox link for this if possible?

Comment: yes added to the post. also here: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_hoobank

Comment: there was an issue with one of the objects i was importing. there want a return on the class